# How to reload the page after successful upload in the Simple Local Avatars WordPress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using [Simple Local Avatars](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/simple-local-avatars/) to allow my blog's authors to upload an avatar.

My aim is to refresh the page after successful upload. My first thought was to look in the `simple-local-avatars.php` source code for an action hook. I was hoping there would be a hook such as `avatar_upload_success` near the end of the `edit_user_profile_update` method but nothing like that is available. So I need to find an alternative way to refresh the page.

How else can I refresh the page after successful upload?

**UPDATE:** Just to make my question a little clearer, my problem isn't how to reload the page, my problem is how do I reload the page on upload success only. For example: On upload failure I don't want to reload.

**UPDATE 2:** So my next attempt was to do something like this:

```
function simple_local_avatar_reload() {
    $url = 'whatever the current page is';
    wp_redirect( $url );
    exit();
}
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'simple_local_avatar_reload', 99 );
```

But that causes the dreaded 'headers already sent' error.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to enable output buffering conditionally and then perform a page refresh after `edit_user_profile_update` has been completed. For example:

```
/**
 * Enable output buffering.
*/
function output_buffer() {
    if ( isset ( $_POST['submit'] ) )
        ob_start();
}
add_action( 'init', 'output_buffer' );

/**
 * Refresh page after avatar upload.
*/
function simple_local_avatar_reload() {
    header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
}
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'simple_local_avatar_reload', 99 );
```

**Note:** This performs a reload even if the upload fails. But it's a workaround I'm going to have to run with unless I modify the plugin's core (which I don't want to do).